# Phonegap Android: Load local html from hosted application

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

At startup, my Phonegap application loads a hosted application (cordova is loaded from there). In certain cases (events) I want to redirect the user to an html file that lives in the phone.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

I've tried redirecting to `file:///android_asset/www/index.html` but doesn't seems to work.

Maybe a PhoneGap plugin that exposes Android's `loadUrl()` to JavaScript?

**EDIT:** I'm using Phonegap 2.8

Comment: Weird, what method did you use to redirect? Have you tried testing a simple `<a href="file:///android_asset/www/index.html">`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and `window.location`

Comment: What about `navigator.app.loadUrl`? According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803020/navigator-app-undefined), window.open should work too

Comment: @RGraham navigator.app.loadUrl worked! Can you please add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `navigator.app.loadUrl`:

```
navigator.app.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```